# Cant Acess The Voice Model File

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk, pyaudio

I am trying to write a code for voice assistant but having problem in accessing my **voiceModel** file after saving.

Can anyone help me out please:)

My Code:

```
def talk(voiceModel):
    print(voiceModel)
    for line in voiceModel.splitlines():
        text_to_speech=gTTS(text='Welcome To Inspiration',lang='en-uk')
        text_to_speech.save('voiceModel.mp3')
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load('voiceModel.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
        os.remove("voiceModel.mp3")
```

And I Got this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Harsh/Desktop/Projects/Python/Inspiration/Inspire.py", line 23, in talk
    os.remove("voiceModel.mp3")

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'voiceModel.mp3'
```

So I just want help to be within limit of accessing my file always without changing my program code a lot:
Plzz Help???

Btw I went here but its not much of help to me [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818922/errno-13-permission-denied-file-mp3-python)

Comment: Anyone plzz help,

Comment: It looks like you need to close the file after playing it. But I have no idea what `mixer` is, so you'll need to refer to their API

Comment: sure , thanks ,  ***mixer is a pygame library to output  text to voice messages as per what I know***